# PhpStorm doesn't recognize method, class

Tags: phpstorm

First time it happen with PhpStorm and only in this project. PhpStorm underline all my methods. My code is still working but I don't have any completion and that annoying.

I deleted the plugins and I cleaned the cache but the problem is still remaining.

I need help for this problem, it's so annoying.

Here an example of what I get:

[image]

Comment: The same on PhpStorm Issue Tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-60880

Comment: So what the errors are? I saw "unknown class/function" only in 2021.2 EAP build -- was caused by incompatible plugin. Once I have disabled it it works OK. You are using stable 2021.1.3 so it's different. Please try disabling Code With Me plugin and restart IDE.

Comment: youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-60880 It's mine.
There is no errors, phpStorm just don't recognise it. The website work but no autocompletion, nothing

Comment: 1) *"There is no errors, phpStorm just don't recognise it*" If it does not recognize it then it marks such unknown stuff with an error/warning. Why some stuff is underlined, some with yellow background .. and some PHP standard functions are not marked at all. So what are the messages? 2) IDE marked `Timber\Timber` as unknown as I understand. Do you have that file in this project? Can you open it in the editor and who the whole IDE window so it shows the file content, that file in the Project View panel and in Navigation Bar -- I'm looking for some clues/hints.